# What's the most common and recommended directory for a web application on FreeBsd?

Tags: freebsd, directory, path

I have a website on a FreeBSD server which is reachable from the Internet. I know I can run it from whichever directory I wish. But still, which directory is more right, common and recommended? At the moment I'm running it from /usr/local/my_website123

Your advice?

Comment: It is a very flavor thing. I typically prefer to have a /srv directory, where all services are running from. But it is a linux custom, freebsd likes /usr/local .

Answer (score 1):

Such questions are asked to [`man hier`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), but it doesn't say anything about `/www`.

Apache runs its default host from `/usr/local/www/apache2x/data`, so I guess `/usr/local/www/my_website` is generally fine.

Comment: And the most web applications installed into `/usr/local/www` so I suggest this directory too.